# How to Fix Irreversible damage due to a module in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

This has been extremely frustrating. I installed a module [Finder](http://drupal.org/project/finder/) in Drupal installation. I was tweaking some settings in it and then after changing some settings it started showing off some Ajax errors and then there was the White Screen, showing this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function views_include() in /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/views/includes/plugins.inc on line 9

Using Drush, I disabled the Finder module and cleared the cache. But nothing happened. Then I disabled the Views module. The White Screen was now gone.

And now I am stuck. I had some pretty good work done in this site and when I re-enable the Views, White Screen reappears. It seems to me like the Finder module made some irreversible changes somewhere in Views. I mean how come my Views is not working when I've cleared the cache and Finder is disabled?

Has anybody ever come across such a thing in Drupal? How did you solve it?

**UPDATE**
I just found that the developer of the "Finder" module is claiming it to be a bug in Views. See here: http://drupal.org/node/1611106. As suggested, commenting out that particular line 9 in plugins.inc of Views module does work. However, I'm still skeptical to accept to be a bug in Views.

Comment: You should *always* back up data before making potentially damaging changes. Other than that I can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: Yep. This was a hard and bitter lesson. From now on, I am never proceeding anywhere without regular backups.

Comment: The error message mentions 'views' twice, so I don't know why you'd be  sceptical of it being a Views bug.

Comment: I am skeptical because Views was working absolutely fine before installing Finder module.

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments because Chimera was not constructive. It sure is easy to chastise someone for not backing up before making a "potentially damaging change". How is anyone supposed to know the change is potentially damaging before they make it? Luckily shivams took the right lesson to make *regular* backups, which is the only way you're going to get a backup made anywhere close to right before the damage you weren't expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got this error too. Funny enough it was also while playing around with settings in the finder module. Playing with the ajax settings to be precise.

Anyway, to get your site back when you get the error and white screen, close your browser and reopen it a a page other than your site and clear all the browser cache. You should then be able to see your site again.

It happen to me after setting 'Ajax' to 'yes' under the form heading on the edit finder page.
After you have reopened your browser and cleared the browser cache, go straight to the edit page for the finder that is the culprit and set 'ajax' to 'no'.

Answer (score 3):

It's not Finder; it's either Drush botching an update or perhaps you relocating the module, causing the registry to become out-of-date. Check that views.module actually exists, Views is enabled in the system table and then [rebuild the registry](http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) as *nmc* suggested.

That should fix it but, at worst, you can comment out the `views_include('base');` call at the top of plugins.inc as a quick hack to recover your site.

Comment: Thanks. Commenting out view_include() did work but it looks like a temporary fix. Let me see if commenting out doesn't cause problem anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Registry Rebuild module may help you.

> When would you need Registry Rebuild?
>
> You might get something like:
>
> `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'EntityAPIControllerExportable' not found in`
>   `...sites/all/modules/rules/includes/rules.core.inc on line 11`
>
> If this happens when you're trying to run update.php, and happens when
>   you're trying to clear your cache, well, you have some trouble. That's
>   what Registry Rebuild is for.

I've never used it myself so I recommend that you look into the code before running it but I hope it helps you.

See 
http://randyfay.com/node/105 and 
http://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild

Comment: registry rebuild may be also be run from drush. Use 'drush rr'.

Answer (score 1):

For me, rebuilding the registry with `drush rr` didn't work. Disabling the module, uninstalling ad reinstalling didn't help also. The only thing which worked was to clear the `sessions` table.